# Can the size of a Semaphore be related to the order of execution of Threads?

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

Looking at some literature for the 1Z0-804 exam, I find this example question for it:

> **Consider the following program:**

```
class ATMRoom {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Semaphore machines = new Semaphore(2); //#1
        new Person(machines, "Mickey");
        new Person(machines, "Donald");
        new Person(machines, "Tom");
        new Person(machines, "Jerry");
        new Person(machines, "Casper");
    }
}

class Person extends Thread {
    private Semaphore machines;
    public Person(Semaphore machines, String name) {
        this.machines = machines;
        this.setName(name);
        this.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(getName()
                + " waiting to access an ATM machine");
                machines.acquire();
            System.out.println(getName()
                + " is accessing an ATM machine");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(getName()
                + " is done using the ATM machine");
            machines.release();
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            System.err.println(ie);
        }
    }
}
```

> **Which one of the options is true if you replace the statement #1 with the following statement?** `Semaphore machines = new Semaphore(2, true);`
>
> *Omitting the answers*

The explanation on the correct answer caught my attention:

> The second parameter states the fairness policy of the semaphore object. However, **there
>   are two permits for the semaphore object; so you cannot predict the order** in which waiting
>   people will get the permission to access the ATM.

I would say that one can not predict the order simply because of the non-deterministic nature of threads, not because of the number of permits in the Semaphore, and that the fairness parameter guarantees that waiting threads are awakened in the same order they acquired the semaphore, but still the acquiring order can not be determined. Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, yes, your idea is correct, since fair semaphore uses FairSync, and it' acquire mechanism does not relay on the number of available permits, but only on the first thread in thread queue:

```
        protected int tryAcquireShared(int acquires) {
        for (;;) {
            if (getFirstQueuedThread() != Thread.currentThread() &&
                hasQueuedThreads())
                return -1;
         ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say since they all call `start` in their constructor you can only guarantee the order of the creation of the threads and their start order, you cannot say anything about the order that their `run` methods get called.

So - essentially - you are correct, the number of semaphores plays no part in the order at all.